# Can i view tables which are under Partition in my sql

Tags: mysql

Can i view tables which are under Partition in my sql???
How to view such tables???

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you mean *"How do I see which tables are using partinioning in MySQL"* and you are using at least MySQL 5.1.6. then you can use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitions-table.html) table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link to obtain the details about table partitions from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitions-table.html